# How can I use ag-grid with Observable in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, ag-grid

I have done lots of research on Internet but still cannot glue these together. I have an angular2 application, with Observable data source from HTTP, and would like to use ag-grid. The problem is I only got a loading screen instead of the data. I have investigated with Fiddler, the data is loaded successfully and correctly in JSON. Here is my code:

order.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Order } from './order';

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

  private ordersUrl = '(Some JSON data source via Internet)';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { } 

  getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.ordersUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  save(order: Order): Observable<Order>  {
    if (order.id) {
      //return this.put(order);
    }
    return this.post(order);
  }

  delete(order: Order) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let url = `${this.ordersUrl}/${order.id}`;

    return this.http
       .delete(url, headers)
       .map(this.extractData)
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  // Add new Order
  private post(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    return this.http
               .post(this.ordersUrl, JSON.stringify(order), {headers: headers})
               .map(this.extractData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

order.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';

import { Order }                from './order';
import { OrderService }         from './order.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-orders',
  templateUrl: 'app/order/order.html',
  directives: [ AgGridNg2 ]
})

export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    orders: Order[];
    selectedOrder: Order;
    addingOrder = false;
    error: any;
    mode = 'Observable';
    gridOptions: any = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getOrders();
    }

    columnDefs = [(Some definition)];

    getOrders() {
        this.orderService
            .getOrders()
            .subscribe(
               orders => this.orders = orders,
               error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private orderService: OrderService) {
            orderService
                .getOrders()
                .subscribe(
                   orders => this.orders = orders,
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

            this.gridOptions = {
                rowData: this.orders,
                columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
                enableColResize: true,
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFilter: true
            }
        }

    onSelect(order: Order) {
        this.selectedOrder = order;
        this.addingOrder = false;
    }
}
```

The above code was copied from Google tutorial with some modifications and for demonstration only.

Here is the HTML file, it contains nothing but one tag for ag-grid

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Thank you in advance for saving my life.

Comment: Please show us your HTML template, too!

Comment: @rinukkusu, Thank you for commenting here and the tag is added.

Comment: What about using the datasource? I have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349631/angular2-ag-grid-datasource-now-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so your flow with the `Observable` looks fine to me, but you don't bind the orders to the grid:

```html
<ag-grid-ng2 
    #agGrid 
    style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" 
    class="ag-fresh" 

   [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
   [rowData]="orders">
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Alternatively you could move the setting of the `gridOptions` into the subscribe callback:

```
    private orderService: OrderService) {
        orderService
            .getOrders()
            .subscribe(
                orders => { 
                    this.orders = orders;

                    this.gridOptions = {
                        rowData: this.orders,
                        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
                        enableColResize: true,
                        enableSorting: true,
                        enableFilter: true
                    };
                },
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
```

---

[This Github Repository](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example/blob/master/app/app.component.html) has some good examples on how to use `ag-grid-ng2`.

Comment: so what you mean is adding the binding into gridOptions is not correct, but I should add the data binding directly to the tag, since I'm using Observable.

Comment: Yes, because of the async nature of http calls, the `this.orders` variable is not set yet, when you assign it in the `gridOptions`. But you could move the assignment into the subscribe callback, too. If you want to edit the `this.orders` array and reflect the changes onto the grid, you have to bind it directly like I proposed.

Comment: finally I found out that I've made an stupid mistake. In the function "extractData", the return value of "body.data" is not align with the JSON response and in result returning NULL. After removing the ".data" then it works totally fine.

Comment: Thanks. also I use [rowData]="projects | async"