# Bind ag-grid with angular2 observable

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to load data into ag-grid when the component loads.
Combining the [example on ag-grid github](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example/blob/master/app/full-width-renderer.component.ts) and the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347308/3325503) I have this ngOnInit for my component:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.promisesService.getPromises()
        .subscribe((s: Promise[]) => {
            console.log('got response:', s);

            this.gridOptions = {
                enableSorting: true,
                rowData: this.createRowData(),
                columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
                onGridReady: () => {
                    this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                    console.log('ag-grid ready');
                }
            };

            console.log('options set:', this.gridOptions);
        });
}
```

The grid is stuck on the "Loading..." with no error messages. The gridOptions are set correctly and its rowData contains all the data I was expecting to see.
The onGridReady is never triggered though.

If I move the setting of the options outside subscribe it works fine:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.promisesService.getPromises()
        .subscribe((s: Promise[]) => {
            console.log('got response:', s);

            console.log('options set:', this.gridOptions);
        });

    this.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        rowData: this.createRowData(),
        columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
        onGridReady: () => {
            this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            console.log('ag-grid ready');
        }
    };


}
```

In the template I am only setting the options:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-ng2>
```

I've tried moving the code into the constructor and setting the rowData in the template but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if I set the options in the constructor and leave the fetching of the data in the Init it works fine. Anyone knows the reason, please let me know:

```
export class PromisesListComponent {
private gridOptions: GridOptions;
promises: Promise[];

constructor(private promisesService: PromisesService) {
    this.gridOptions = {
        rowData: this.promises,
        columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        onGridReady: () => {
            this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
    }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.promisesService.getPromises()
        .subscribe((response: Promise[]) => {
            this.promises = response;
        });
}

private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
        {
            headerName: "Agreement Code",
            field: "AgreementCode",
            width: 200
        }
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: I think the issue that you are running into is the rowData value. This, I believe, is expecting some static ready at that moment data. Where it is that you are using promises, it might work best to run the `gridOptions.api.setRowData()` or `gridOptions.api.setDatasource()` functions inside of the subscribe